# Help with importing specific tags in XML Document with PHP SimpleXML

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

This is my PHP:

```
  $link='resources/xml/weap'.$wxid.'.xml';
  $xml=new SimpleXMLElement($link, 0, true);
```

This is my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<weapons>
 <weap>
  <value>101</value>
  <name>Kortsv&#228;rd</name>
  <mindmg>2</mindmg>
  <maxdmg>5</maxdmg>
  <lvl>1</lvl>
  <hands>1</hands>
  <range>4</range>
 </weap>
 <weap>
  <value>102</value>
  <name>L&#229;ngsv&#228;rd</name>
  <mindmg>3</mindmg>
  <maxdmg>7</maxdmg>
  <lvl>2</lvl>
  <hands>1</hands>
  <range>7</range>
 </weap>
...and continues likes this.
</weapons>
```

However, I would like to import the name of a specific  depending on what's in the -tag.
Normally, I do this: $test=$xml->blablabla->blabla; however, I can not choose a from a specific tag with it.
Anye help?

EDIT: It's OK if I have to do minor changes to the XML document.

(sorry for bad english)

Answer (score 1):

Try to use the function [simplexml_load_file()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-file.php).
It will return a SimpleXMLElement object, and you can convert to array with cast.

Comment: Sorry, can you explain a bit more?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [xpath method](https://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.xpath.php) in order to get the list of required nodes.